# Detect when a user leaves a page and write a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am implementing a cookie banner and need to have inferred consent once the user has seen the banner. I am therefore trying to write a cookie once the user starts to navigate the site to say they've seen the cookie banner. I've tried using beforeunload and unload, but neither seem to do anything.

The latest bit of code I've used this is:

```
<script>
                    $(window).unload(function () {
                        jQuery.post("/set-cookie-preference", { cookiePreference: 3 },
                       function (data) {
                           //document.location.reload();
                       });
                    });
                </script>
```

I also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function closeIt() {
                        jQuery.post("/set-cookie-preference", { cookiePreference: 3 },
                           function (data) {
                               //document.location.reload();
                           });
                    }
                    window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
                </script>
```

But neither seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using JavaScript to set the cookie? Why the post to the server? Unload is way to late to make an Ajax call, it will not make it to the server.

Comment: There's a pre-built solution here http://cookiecuttr.com/

Comment: Server not receive `$.post()` `data` ?

Comment: @DevlshOne that site has been like removed or deleted... so sad they took down the site but its still on github

Answer (score -2):

You could use LocalStorage. It works the same like a cookie, but it has some more benefits, in my opinion. A LocaStorage object can only be removed by the user (like when we wipes his browser history). To set a normal PHP cookie you have to set a time.

You can read more about it here:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

All major browsers (Chrome, IE, FireFox, Safari) support LocalStorage. Even IE 8 supports LocalStorage!

Comment: He was asking how he could set the cookie, not a better alternative to a cookie.